# Calculate Total vote as subtractive upvote to downvote with group by conditon in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
Database table: 
+----------------------------------------------+
| vote_id | user_id | vote_type | fieldset_id  |
+----------------------------------------------+
|   1     |  1      |  up       |  111         |
|   2     |  2      |  up       |  111         |
|   3     |  3      |  down     |  111         |
|   4     |  4      |  up       |  111         |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Mysql Query:

```
select vote_type,count(vote_type) as total_vote 
   from vote_mst 
   where fieldset_id='111' 
   group by vote_type
```

Expected Output:  **+3**

While i am getting

```
+-------------------------+
| vote_type  | total_vote |
+-------------------------+
|   up       |  3         |
|   down     |  1         |
+-------------------------+
```

as calculating (Upvote-Downvote) inside MysQL Query

Comment: Why is `+3` the expected output? The net votes is +2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select `fieldset_id`,`vote_type`,SUM(IF(`vote_type`='up',1,-1)) as `total_vote` 
from `vote_mst` 
GROUP BY `fieldset_id`
```

Comment: perfect solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select sum(vote_type = 'up') - sum(vote_type = 'down') as net_votes,
       count(*) as total_votes
from vote_mst 
where fieldset_id = '111' ;
```